# how to send html report using slack-node?

Tags: node.js, automation, slack-api, slack-commands

In my automation framework, I am generating a html test report at the end of the test scripts. I want to post this html report to a slack channel. I tried it using node-slack-upload module but couldn't upload though messages get posted successfully. below is my code:

```
slack.uploadFile({
            file: fs.createReadStream("test.html"),
            filetype: 'post',
            title: "Skyline API Automation Report",
            channel: "#skylineautomation"
        }, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("inside error");
                console.error(err);
            }
            else {
                console.log('done');
            }
        });
```

Comment: It seems you have a typo in a parameter name, can you try by replacing `channel` with `channels`?

Comment: Have a look at [DOCUMENTATION](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-slack-upload) . @Signo is right

Comment: What is your issue exactly? Do you get an error message or it it something else?